# exec-maven-plugin ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to start a jar from a dependency with the exec-maven-plugin

Thats the Code in my Project "MainProject" inside the POM

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>generate-jpaentities</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>basicMaven.BasicMavenApplication</mainClass>
            <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
            <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>basicProjects</groupId>
         <artifactId>BasicMaven</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Thats the Code in the BasicMaven Project

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
           <archive>
              <manifest>
                 <mainClass>basicMaven.BasicMavenApplication</mainClass>
              </manifest>
           </archive>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

i did an `"mvn install"` inside the basicMaven Project Folder.

and tried to start the plugin inside my MainProject Folder with

```
mvn clean package
```

But i get the Error that the class is not found

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: basicMaven.BasicMavenApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:246)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
```

so i looked up my .m2 folder
There is my BasicMaven jar File

when i looked inside of it with "jar -tf BasicMaven.jar"

i got the following output:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/springframework/
org/springframework/boot/
org/springframework/boot/loader/
org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$DefinePackageCallType.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/MainMethodRunner.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ClassPathArchives.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$Entry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$EntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$AbstractIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$ArchiveIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$SimpleJarFileArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile$JarFileType.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AsciiBytes.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64End.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64Locator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryParser.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/FileHeader.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntry.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryCertification.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$JarEntryEnumeration.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileWrapper.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$1.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/StringSequence.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/ZipInflaterInputStream.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarMode.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarModeLauncher.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/TestJarMode.class
org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
BOOT-INF/
BOOT-INF/classes/
BOOT-INF/classes/xsd/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/maven/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/maven/common/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/maven/common/BasicMaven/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/maven/common/BasicMaven/util/
BOOT-INF/classes/swagger/
BOOT-INF/classes/basicMaven/
BOOT-INF/classes/basicMaven/api/
BOOT-INF/classes/basicMaven/api/type/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/basicProjects/
META-INF/maven/basicProjects/BasicMaven/
```

I think that there should be something like

```
basicMaven/BasicMavenApplication
```

but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: Is your project a spring boot project? If yes don't use exec and jar plugin use the spring-boot-maven-plugin instead that produces an executable jar....which is startable via `java -jar xyz.jar`...

Comment: i tried it, but the jar contains the same output like posted above.

Comment: Where should `BasicMavenApplication` ? Have you created a class like this including the appropriate package? How does that class look like? Best would be a full working example on Github or a link to your project....because you seemed to misunderstand the intention of a spring boot application also how to use it